# Why is scalafmt gluing these lines together?

Tags: scala, scalafmt

I have this type definition:

```
type Foo = Bar
   with Baz
   with Bat
   with Bak
   with Bar
```

Which I like formatted the way it is.
But even with `newlines.source=keep` scalafmt glues them all into one line (and what's even worse, breaks it into too lines if it ends up being longer than `maxColumn`):

```
type Foo = Bar with Baz with Bat with Bak
  with Bar
```

... which, to me, looks completely unreadable :(

Why is it doing this, and is there a setting that would make it preserve my formatting?

**Update**
In response to comments, here is the entire script:

```
[sandbox] [1123]> cat .scalafmt.conf
version = "3.7.16"
runner.dialect = scala213
newlines.source=keep
maxColumn = 40
[sandbox] [1124]> scalafmt --version
scalafmt 3.7.16
[sandbox] [1125]> scalafmt --test foobar.scala 
--- a/Users/dima/sandbox/foobar.scala
+++ b/Users/dima/sandbox/foobar.scala
@@ -1,9 +1,4 @@
 class Foo {
-  type It = Foo with
-    Bar with
-    Baz with
-    Bat with
-    Bak with
-    Bam with
-    Ban
+  type It = Foo with Bar with Baz
+    with Bat with Bak with Bam with Ban
 }
error: --test failed
```

Comment: What version os `scalafmt` are you using?

Comment: Could you share the configuration you are using for scalafmt? Which scala version? Which scalafmt version?

Comment: @stefanobaghino, I have added the complete details to the question

Comment: @GastónSchabas I updated the question with the details.

Comment: I copyied pasted your `.scalafmt.conf` and the class `Foo` provided, applied format from Intellij and also tried to execute `sbt scalafmt`. In both cases none of the lines were changed. When I set the value of `newlines.source` to `fold` or `unfold` it changes the code. I used `scalafmt 3.7.15`. For some reason when I tried to use `3.7.16` I got `Classpath is corrupted`. Not sure if there is some issue in my local env or it is related with what you are trying to do

Comment: yeah, I get classpath is corrupted with sbt and 3.7.16 too ... But 3.7.15 does the same thing for me in sbt as 1.17.16 on command line  Weird, I think, when I tried to create a MRE, I think, I saw it actually work correctly once, so then I thought maust be something special with my actual class, so I started throwing stuff out of it gradually trying to isolate it ... But eventually I ended up with this Foo, and it still wasn't working 